# How could I read a Markdown list into a Python OrderedDict?

Tags: python, list, markdown, ordereddictionary

I have Markdown lists of the following form:

```
- launchers
   - say hello
      - command: echo "hello" | festival --tts
      - icon: shebang.svg
   - say world
      - command: echo "world" | festival --tts
      - icon: shebang.svg
   - say date
      - command: date | festival --tts
```

I have a function that can convert this Markdown list to a dictionary, like the following:

```
{'say world': {'command': 'echo "world" | festival --tts', 'icon': 'shebang.svg'}, 'say hello': {'command': 'echo "hello" | festival --tts', 'icon': 'shebang.svg'}, 'say date': {'command': 'date | festival --tts'}}
```

When I do this, obviously the ordering is lost. What would be an appropriate way to keep this ordering? Would a plain list be good? Would an OrderedDict be better? How should it be done?

What I have so far is shown below as a minimal working example:

```
import re

def Markdown_list_to_dictionary(Markdown_list):
    line = re.compile(r"( *)- ([^:\n]+)(?:: ([^\n]*))?\n?")
    depth = 0
    stack = [{}]
    for indent, name, value in line.findall(Markdown_list):
        indent = len(indent)
        if indent > depth:
            assert not stack[-1], "unexpected indent"
        elif indent < depth:
            stack.pop()
        stack[-1][name] = value or {}
        if not value:
            # new branch
            stack.append(stack[-1][name])
        depth = indent
    return(stack[0])

Markdown_list =\
"""
- launchers
   - say hello
      - command: echo "hello" | festival --tts
      - icon: shebang.svg
   - say world
      - command: echo "world" | festival --tts
      - icon: shebang.svg
   - say date
      - command: date | festival --tts
"""

print(Markdown_list_to_dictionary(Markdown_list))
```

Comment: simple answer: yes, use an `OrderedDict` if you want to preserve your order in the dictionary. using a simple list wouldn't be able to give you the kind of structure that you seem to want since theres no way of adding a title/call name to an internal list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an OrderedDict looks like it should work in this circumstance. You code would then look something like this:

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict as _OrderedDict

def Markdown_list_to_dictionary(Markdown_list):
    line = re.compile(r"( *)- ([^:\n]+)(?:: ([^\n]*))?\n?")
    depth = 0
    stack = [_OrderedDict()]
    for indent, name, value in line.findall(Markdown_list):
        indent = len(indent)
        if indent > depth:
            assert not stack[-1], "unexpected indent"
        elif indent < depth:
            stack.pop()
        stack[-1][name] = value or _OrderedDict()
        if not value:
            # new branch
            stack.append(stack[-1][name])
        depth = indent
    return(stack[0])

Markdown_list =\
"""
- launchers
   - say hello
      - command: echo "hello" | festival --tts
      - icon: shebang.svg
   - say world
      - command: echo "world" | festival --tts
      - icon: shebang.svg
   - say date
      - command: date | festival --tts
"""

print(Markdown_list_to_dictionary(Markdown_list))
```

And the output like this:

```
OrderedDict([('launchers', OrderedDict([('say hello', OrderedDict([('command', 'echo "hello" | festival --tts'), ('icon', 'shebang.svg')])), ('say world', OrderedDict([('command', 'echo "world" | festival --tts'), ('icon', 'shebang.svg')])), ('say date', OrderedDict([('command', 'date | festival --tts')]))]))])
```

It isn't as nice to look at when printed, but it does function correctly.